# How do i Duplicate a line in Richtextbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

test 123

after click "duplicate":

test 123
test 123

No matter where the cursor is
copy the entire line to the next line

i tried:

```
int selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
int lineStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
int lineEnd = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart) + 1);

if (lineEnd == -1)
{
    // Last line in the RichTextBox
    lineEnd = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
}

string selectedLine = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);

// Insert the duplicated line after the current line
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(lineEnd, Environment.NewLine + selectedLine);

// Move the cursor to the end of the duplicated line
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = lineEnd + Environment.NewLine.Length;
            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

thanks, but i solved my problem

```
    int currentLine = EditingArea.GetLineFromCharIndex(EditingArea.SelectionStart);
    int lineCharIndex = EditingArea.SelectionStart;
    string[] lines = EditingArea.Lines;
    string[] newLines = new string[lines.Length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < newLines.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == currentLine) lineCharIndex += lines[i].Length + 1;
        if (i > currentLine)
        {
            newLines[i] = lines[i - 1];
            continue;
        }
        newLines[i] = lines[i];
    }
    EditingArea.Lines = newLines;
    EditingArea.SelectionStart = lineCharIndex;
```

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it, which is good, but you have explained what actually happens when you try it. You need to explain exactly what happens and where and how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the lines that those methods deal with are actual physical lines. That means that, if you have word wrap enabled, two lines in the control may not have a line break between them. Are those the lines you want or do you actually care about substrings separated by line breaks?

Comment: Your `lineEnd` already includes the New Line char (single, the RichTextBox Control doesn't use `Environment.NewLine` as line separator, it uses `\n`). So, you have to add the line feed only when you're duplicating the last line; in all other cases, you're already copying the line feed along with the rest of the text in that line, otherwise you end up adding an empty line

Comment: Also, as already mentioned, you have to specify whether you want to duplicate a logical or a physical line (which depends on the size of the Control and the state of the `WordWrap` property)

Comment: I would tend to use the `Lines` property, which is a `string` array. Create a collection from the array first. Get the line number, which you may be able to do using those RTB methods if word wrap is not enabled, and just duplicate it within the collection. Create a new array from the collection and assign it back to the `Lines` property.

Comment: sorry, I didnt explain what happen to it, i just solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
int selectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
int lineStart = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();
int lineEnd = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(selectionStart) + 1);
if (lineEnd == -1)
{
    lineEnd = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
}
string selectedLine = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(lineStart, lineEnd - lineStart);
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Insert(lineEnd, Environment.NewLine + selectedLine);
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = lineStart;
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = selectedLine.Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;
richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

Comment: Just mentioned in comments that the RichTextBox doesn't use `Environment.NewLine` as line separator -- You also forgot to describe what problem this code is meant to solve and how it solves it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).